# Setting up Entity Framework in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am working on an `ASP.NET Core` application that is running under the full `.NET Framework 4.6.1`. I am using `Entity Framework 6` since `Entity Framework Core` has some limitations as of now (specially with many-to-many relationships). I am trying to understand how to properly setup and use Entity Framework through `ASP.NET Core`'s Dependency Injection.

**Question 1**

Should MyContext inherit `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` or `Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext`?

**Question 2**

Which of these would be the correct way of setting it up as a service, so that it can be injected in constructors?

```
private const string ConString = "myConnectionString";
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //FIRST WAY - requires MyContext to be of type Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => { });

    //SECOND WAY - requires MyContext to be of type Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext
    services.AddEntityFramework.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => { });

    //THIRD WAY
    services.AddTransient(provider => new MyContext(ConString));

    //FOURTH WAY
    services.AddScoped(provider => new MyContext(ConString));
}
```

Although the differences between `AddTransient` and `AddScoped` are well defined [in the documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html).

**Question 3**

In which of the cases above is this required, assuming that I am using SQL Server?

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1:** System.Data.Entity.DbContext

**Question 2:**

```
services.AddScoped(provider => new MyContext(ConString));
```

you want 1 context per web request

**Question 3:** you don't need this

Those other extension are for using EF Core NOT EF 6

Comment: Not sure why there are three namespaces (System.Data, Microsoft.Data and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore) for the same framework, but thanks for the answer! Microsoft should remove those EF Core extensions and put them in the EF Core package

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()`:

If you are using within ASP.NET:

> You are simply not supposed to call AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer() on your ASP.NET container - that configures all of EF's services on that container; the right way to use EF in almost all cases is to let it configure its own internal service provider. In other words, just call UseSqlServer() as indicated in all the tutorials, and EF will set up an internal DI service provider (completely distinct from the ASP.NET one), and will configure its own internal IMemoryCache there.

From https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12905

Answer (score -1):

**First qauestion:**
`using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` works well in my project.

**Second question:** your first way is correct

**Third question:** If you configure everything like that you don't need to add `services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();`

Comment: What do you base the second answer on?

Comment: I checked all settings of `Entity Framework Core` in my `.Net Core`project witch works correct. I had the same problems and only that settings works fine obviously fo my case.

Comment: But that, as you said, is for `Entity Framework Core` which is very different to `Entity Framework 6`